# Android Beginner: Adapter for simple view or direct DB query?

Tags: android, database, cursor, adapter

First off I'm really new to android (< 4 days).

I'm trying to wrap my head around how database data is linked to Views and widgets.

I've done a few tutorials and I've noticed that Adapters are used to link AdapterViews which are (as I understand it) Views which contain a bunch of identical subviews (eg lists, gallery, etc).  So the Adapter is responsible for creating those subviews and populating the data for each one (correct me if I'm wrong).

Now let's say I have a list view which lists Hotels for example.  Each row in the list has the Hotel's name and a basic rating (eg 5 star).  Now when you tap on a hotel in the list a new activity shows up showing the details of that particular hotel.  All the data is in a database.  I understand that you have an adapter manage the data<->view link for the list, but what's the best way to then manage data for the hotel details view (which is not a list but just a couple of text views and an image for example)?

Is it best to just pass the ID in the intent and then have the details activity fetch the data from the DB on its own (in this case do I store the query in the details activity?)?  Or do you get all the fields you need and put those in the intent directly?  Do you need an adapter for a view which doesn't actually generate lots of similar subviews?

I guess a summary of my question is what do you use instead of an adapter when you're not dealing with adapterviews but just simple straightforward single views.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Great question and excellently asked - I have the same dilemma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it best to just pass the ID in the intent and then have the details activity fetch the data from the DB
>   on its own (in this case do I store the query in the details activity?)?

That is what I would recommend.

> Do you need an adapter for a view which doesn't actually generate lots of similar subviews?

No. You only use an `Adapter` with an `AdapterView` (`ListView`, `Spinner`, etc.)

> I guess a summary of my question is what do you use instead of an adapter when you're not dealing with
>   adapterviews but just simple straightforward single views.

Just the `Cursor` from the database. Get the fields from the (one) row in the `Cursor`, put them in the `EditText` widgets, and when the user makes changes, update the row.

Comment: Makes sense to me.  Thanks for the simple answer.

Answer (score 0):

@CommonsWare is bang on. As a code example, I was able to DRY things up by creating a helper method to dynamically set the TextViews a little cleaner.

In my **`onCreate()`** I have a number of the following lines:

```java
bindTextView(hotel, "uid");   // `hotel` is the Hotel object with attributes.
```

And then I define **`bindTextView()`** below as follows:

```java
protected void bindTextView( Hotel hotel, String attribute ) {

    try {

        // Get field for object dynamically.
        Field field = hotel.getClass().getField(attribute); 

        // Invoke field "getter" method to get value.
        String value = field.get(hotel).toString();                                                                   

        // Get resource id dynamically.
        int resourceId = R.id.class.getField(attribute).getInt(null);                                               

        // Get element with resource id.
        TextView element = (TextView) this.findViewById( resourceId );                                              

        // Finally, set the element's text value.
        element.setText( value );

    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) { e.printStackTrace();                                                       

    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e)   { e.printStackTrace(); }                                                     

}
```

*I actually moved this helper method to a base `Activity` class since it's shared amongst a number of different activities.*

I hope that helps some people keep their activities clean.

JP